# How is American Exceptionalism shown throughout the Bioshock Titles?

Tags: bioshock-series

As I am reading through a wiki on Bioshock it mentions Bioshock Infinite having a connection to the other titles through a theme. The theme being [American Exceptionalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_exceptionalism), which is easily noticable in Bioshock Infinite (even with it not being released yet) but not as noticable in the other two titles.

> while a third game entitled BioShock Infinite by
>   Irrational Games is presently under development, though it is only
>   thematically connected to the previous titles

[Wiki source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioshock)

I've heard this talk from a die hard as well, he mention something similiar although he had a different take on the whole thing.

**So how is American Exceptionalism the theme that connects the Bioshock titles?**

Comment: Not posting this as an answer since its just a link, but it seems like whatever you're trying to learn is probably at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BioShock_Infinite

Comment: @bwarner it mention "Building on the ideas of American Exceptionalism in the early 20th century" which is what I was talking about. But how is that relating to the other two. I think i'm just doing a poor job of getting my point across.

Comment: Check out the first paragraph under development, that seems to explain the relationship pretty well.

Comment: @bwarner "the Irrational team recentered on the idea of American Exceptionalism, a tangible concept that continues to be repeated throughout history" thats exactly what i was talking about.

Comment: 3 downvotes and not a single tip for improvement :c

Comment: I think downvotes only indicate disagreement with the question's direction and whatnot

Comment: @Retrosaur On meta they mean disagreement. Here they mean bad question (or so the voters think).

Comment: I downvoted because I think trying to define what is the "theme" of a gaming series is vague and not useful.

Comment: Edited to hopefully get my point across a little better.

Comment: @bwarner i changed it up a bit to make it less vague, if this isnt better i give up.

Comment: I had upvoted when it was asking about general themes, but now it's a different question.

Comment: @Luck same basic question, it was just to vague for this sites standards, feel free to change your vote to down. Should be possible since i edited it.

Comment: I only played Bioshock 1, but I thought one of the themes was innocence and humanity vs. power and depravity.  Was this not present in part 2?  I assume a similar theme will be present in Infinite with innocence (freedom) vs. power (oppression).

Comment: @Luck thats what im trying to figure out, because Irrational Games has stated (so says the wiki) that they are using American Exceptionalism in their games.

Comment: this question is kinda subjective, I think it may fit in the chat, but not really here...

Comment: @Nacho subjective? no, i'm asking how does Irrational games use american exceptionalism in the first two Bioshock games, how is that an opinion?

Comment: well, it leads to different opinions, that's creating a discussion, thus it's subjective

Comment: @Nacho if that was true then ppl who ask for strategies would be asking subjective questions.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed/downvoted. It is on-topic for this site and is a good question. The FAQ states: "*What kind of questions can I ask here? ...If your question generally covers things such as… **Plot and characters in games** …then you are in the right place to ask your question!*" Also, the question (the current edit) is not worded to elicit opinions (is not subjective). @bwarner I don't think the question is "trying to define what is the 'theme' of a gaming series".

Comment: Subjective, no.  Useful...not so much.  There are no close votes, so it belongs, but quite a few people seem to agree with me.  Remember, downvotes are personal, and trying to tell people that they shouldn't downvote because you don't agree is the reason they're anonymous.  @galacticninja

Comment: @fbueckert "*There are no close votes...*" Saw this on the 'Close Votes' queue on the Review page, so I reckon (might be wrong, though) that someone must have initiated a close vote. "*...trying to tell people that they shouldn't downvote because you don't agree is the reason they're anonymous.*" I don't understand what you mean by this. I know that downvotes are anonymous (but I can see how many downvotes and upvotes a question gets). Do you mean I shouldn't comment on why a question should or should not be downvoted?

Comment: @fbueckert "*Subjective, no. Useful...not so much*" Now, this statement *is* subjective. =) I think it is useful to ask about this aspect of the game's plot.

Comment: @galacticninja *Do you mean I shouldn't comment on why a question should or should not be downvoted?*  Yeah.  That, basically.  I know, personally, that when I get told that, I get annoyed.  I doubt I'm the only one. :)

Comment: @fbueckert I [said](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96475/4797#comment132152_96475) "I don't *think* this question should be closed/downvoted..." and then mentioned *why*. I didn't *tell* anyone what to do, I just merely voiced my opinion on the matter. This is partly due to [OP saying](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96475/4797#comment132084_96475) "3 downvotes and not a single tip for improvement". Personally, I'd rather people comment on why my question/answer should or should not be downvoted/closed, than downvoting/closing without commenting. That is more annoying, to me.

Comment: @galacticninja yay, im not alone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

American Exceptionalism is not the theme of the BioShock series.

**The theme of the BioShock series is 'choice'.**

Creative Director Ken Levine, [on the major themes in the first BioShock](http://www.shacknews.com/article/48587/creative-director-ken-levine-on):

> The back of the box mentions combat alone, with no allusions to the greater themes. Did you find you had to manipulate how you presented the game to different groups?
>
> Ken Levine: You know, marketing it as "The ultimate in first-person Objectivist shooters" is not really the right path to go.

Notice how he doesn't mention American Exceptionalism, but does mention objectivism.

Again, on the series in general:

> "To me, there's two things that make a 'BioShock' game 'BioShock.' They take place in a world that is both fantastic and ridiculous. Something that you've never seen before and something that nobody else could create except Irrational, but it's also strangely grounded and believable. The other thing that makes it a 'BioShock' game, it's about having a huge toolset of power and a huge range of challenges, **and you being able to drive how you solve those challenges**."

[Emphasis added. [Source here]](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1645673/bioshock-infinite-developer-avoided-repeating-original-game.jhtml)

Furthermore, look at Andrew Ryan's "[A man chooses, a slave obeys](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/A_man_chooses,_a_slave_obeys)" and the continuously repeating "Would you kindly..." messages, as well as Delta's drive to save Eleanor in BioShock 2.  Nowhere is American Exceptionalism mentioned, except as it relates to BioShock Infinite, indicating that **it is not a major theme of the series, but rather a theme of that particular game.**

Comment: intermeresting, never would've thought that.